# Dynamics CRM : Create new case for Email forward from 1 Queue to another Queue with in Dynamics CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm

Let's says I am using out-of-the-box Auto Case creation rules and have 2 queues configured in the system: Q1 & Q2.

How can I create a separate (new) case in Q2, if I forward/send an email from the case in Q1 to email address of queue - Q2?

Currently, the forwarded email is coming back to Dynamics and getting linked with the case already present in Q1, though the ownership of new email is with Q2.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a configuration level solution, but never mind, I found a solution with a custom plugin.

I was able to solve it with a sync plugin on email pre-create, and nulling the regarding field in target entity.